# How to separate thousands with comma in angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, separator

in angular 2 or 4 I want numbers be separated in thousand by comma, when it is in input and user typing and when it is just print it.
Do you have any idea or solution to share it?
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe.

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you for your reply but I couldn't understand how to use it

Comment: Just as explained in the examples of the documentation: {{ someNumber | number }}. It's a pipe. It's used as any other pipe.

Answer (score 13):

You have 2 options here:

---

### Pipes (for texts without user interaction)

- For texts (simply displaying something), you can simply use Angular's built-in [Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'number-pipe',
    template: `<div>
    <!--output '25,000.00'-->
    <p>{{mynumber | number:'5.2-2'}}</p>

    <!--output '25 000,00'-->
    <p>{{mynumber | number:'5.2-2':'fr'}}</p>
    </div>`
})
export class NumberPipeComponent {
  mynumber: number = 2500000;
}
```

The `'5.2.2'` part responds to a rule defined like:

`{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`

And be aware that a different `locale` produces different results in terms of using commas or dots when formatting.

---

### Masks (for inputs where the number gets formatted as the user types)

- If you want to format the number as the user types inside an `<input>` you'll need to use a masking library or a formatter solution like this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask) or similar.

After installing the package `npm install ng2-currency-mask --save`, you have to add it to your Module via `imports`

```js
import { CurrencyMaskModule } from "ng2-currency-mask";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        CurrencyMaskModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And finally implement it like:

`<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',' }"/>`

Make sure you check all the different options the package offers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17840656)

Comment: Thanks @lebelinoz, I've edited the answer to include those essential parts.

Answer (score 11):

Just add this pipe `{{ mynumber | number:0 }}`. It will specify that your value is a number. So, it will be comma separated, and then the `"0"` specifies there're no decimals.